# libgif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, lua, docker-compose, luajit

I am having an issue loading the giflib ffi module (https://github.com/leafo/giflib) in my Lapis web application running in Docker.

Here is the relevant information: https://hastebin.com/ojodidodoj.nginx

libgif.so seems to be able to be found since there is no Lua module search output, yet it says that libgif.so cannot be found, so I am very confused by this error, unless I am misunderstanding the output here?

Edit: Here is the Dockerfile: https://hastebin.com/inezemogux.rb

Comment: Is your image Alpine-based? Can you post the Dockerfile so we can rebuild if needed? - Now a wild guess: I have seen something similar with python libs that require `libc`. Alipne uses `musc` which sometime causes linking problems and thus some `.so` files cannot be loaded. If thats the case you can try https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/

Comment: I am using centos, not alpine. I also manually built giflib. I'll add the dockerfile to the OP.

Comment: Ok, show us the Dockerfile and we take from there. The same error message can appear when an `.so` has undefined symbols which can be caused by wrong `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or missing dependencies. Might worth doing an `ldd` on the .so that fails to load..

Comment: Dockerfile is in the OP.

Comment: Here are the results of doing ldd: https://hastebin.com/cereludiya.rb

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to verify `/usr/local/lib` is in the lib path (either `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when you run or `/etc/ld.so.conf*` configs. I will try to build if I find some time later (...@-work)

Comment: It may not quite build properly. I am currently attempting to clean up my project and move it to a docker-compose setup as opposed to running on bare metal. It should build fine but you may need to exec into bash as opposed to using compose up. The original code can be found here: https://github.com/karai17/lapis-chan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to execute `ldconfig` to update the lib cache.